# preg_replace to replace string for matching url

Tags: php, regex

```
function makeLinksInTheContent($html)
{
    $html= preg_replace("/(^|[\n ])([\w]*?)((ht|f)tp(s)?:\/\/[\w]+[^ \,\"\n\r\t<]*)/is", "$1$2<a href=\"$3\" rel=\"nofollow\" >$3</a>", $html);
    $html= preg_replace("/(^|[\n ])([\w]*?)((www|ftp)\.[^ \,\"\t\n\r<]*)/is", "$1$2<a href=\"http://$3\" rel=\"nofollow\" >$3</a>", $html);
    $html= preg_replace("/(^|[\n ])([a-z0-9&\-_\.]+?)@([\w\-]+\.([\w\-\.]+)+)/i", "$1<a href=\"mailto:$2@$3\" rel=\"nofollow\">$2@$3</a>", $html);

    return($html);
}
```

this is my code.

My need is autolinking the url. Using preg_replace to find the url and set link to this url.

for example: "A page contains www.google.com." if i pass this content to makeLinksInTheContent($html), it will return "A page contains [www.google.com](http://www.google.com)."

But The following url format is not getting linked.

1. (http://www.google.com)
2. www.test.com()and[]*&^%$#@!+|!@#$%^&*()_+}{:"?><,./;'[]=-09~`.co,in,com.com
3. http://www.test.com()and[]*&^%$#@!+|!@#$%^&*()_+}{:"?><,./;'[]=-09~`.co,in,com.com
4. https://www.test.com()and[]*&^%$#@!+|!@#$%^&*()_+}{:"?><,./;'[]=-09~`.co,in,com.com
5. ftp://www.test.com()and[]*&^%$#@!+|!@#$%^&*()_+}{:"?><,./;'[]=-09~`.co,in,com.com

I think my regular expression have some mistakes. please suggest us.

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest using my function - just tested with your data and works for me

```
function parse_links($string,$mailto=true)
{
    $preg_r = "#(((https?|ftp)(://)?)?[a-zA-Z0-9-_.]{1,64}\.[a-zA-Z0-9-_.]{1,128}\.[a-z]{2,4}(\.[a-z]{2,4})?(/([^ ]{1,256}))?/?)#";
    $string = preg_replace($preg_r,"<a href=\"http://$1\">$1</a>",explode(" ",$string));
    if($mailto)
    {
        $preg_r2 = "/([0-9a-zA-Z]([-.\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z])*@([0-9a-zA-Z_\-\.][-\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z_\-\.]\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,9})/";
        $string = preg_replace($preg_r2,"<a href=\"mailto:$1\">$1</a>",$string);
    }
    return implode(" ",$string);
}
```

Just pass `false` as second parameter if you don't want email links to be created

Comment: Damn good regex dude! I like the way you are conforming to Apache's (Could be web-wide) url standards with the length of the given url.